# Multiple lines of TeX output between btex and etex in METAPOST

Tags: metapost

As you know, this is how to create labels in METAPOST:

```
label(btex some text etex, (0,0));
```

How do I place text on multiple lines -- in this case such that "some" appears on one line, and "text" appears on the next line? Putting "\\" between them doesn't seem to work at all.

Here is the skeleton of my file:

```
verbatimtex
%&latex 
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
etex
input mp-tool;
beginfig(0);

label(btex some text etex, (0,0));

endfig;
verbatimtex
\end{document}
etex
end
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you using LaTeX to format the labels? Can you make a complete example of your `.mp` file? (Just with the essential bits)

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I have now pasted the skeleton of my document. Also, I should perhaps mention that I then use "mptopdf" to compile it into a PDF file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer may surprise you:

```
verbatimtex
%&latex 
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
etex
input mp-tool;
beginfig(0);

label(btex \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} some \\ text \end{tabular} etex, (0,0));

endfig;
verbatimtex
\end{document}
etex
end
```

You can also use `\begin{tabular}[t]` or `\begin{tabular}[b]` to modify the vertical alignment.

Comment: Didn't try, but the tabular preamble appears to be missing its closing brace.